# pdf parameter in embed html element

Tags: html, pdf, dom, embed

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%">embed PDF: <br /><embed id="frPDF" height="100%" width="100%" src="C:\Users\a\Desktop\Sample.pdf#page=3&zoom=200,250,100"></embed></div>
```

the above html code when i open in chrome starts the pdf from 3rd page correctly however i want only the 3rd page to be displayed not all. in this case it displays all the pages when scrolled.
i am referring to link https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf but not able to find the answer only to display that particular page. basically i have to restrict the user to view other pages

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with pdf open parameters.

If it is possible you can cut your pdf "Sample.pdf" that remainder only one page (the third) create a new pdf "SamplePage3Only.pdf"

and make `src="C:\Users\a\Desktop\SamplePage3Only.pdf#zoom=200,250,100"`